# Can I do an if else function with a range of values?

Tags: excel

I have two different sheets in excel:

Sheet 1 has values 1 to 15, the second has values 12 to 20. What I want to do on the second sheet is if the first value in sheet 2 is in the first column (range) of sheet 1 then they get an A if not they get a 0. How can I do this?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a place where users can put up a want list and code monkeys churn out code.  It is also not a teach me to code class.  Stack Overflow is dedicated to helping those with existing buggy code, overcome specific problems with said code.  Please post the code you have tried with an explanation of the problems encountered with any error messages and specific lines that are throwing those errors.

Comment: "Stack Overflow is the largest, most trusted online community for developers to learn, share​ ​their programming ​knowledge, and build their careers." I don't even know where to start so how could I give what I attempted. Thanks for the help @ScottCraner

Comment: key word `developers` if you do not know where to start then that word does not apply.

Comment: lol okay best of luck with your developing

Answer (score 1):

In **B1** *Sheet2* enter:

```
=IFERROR(IF(MATCH(A1,Sheet1!A:A,0),"A",0),0)
```

and copy down.